# Double order by on a query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

that I want to get is from the table posts the 8 most rated posts(posts.rates) and the 8 most viewed(posts.views) on the same query, so I get 16 results at all. Both fields are on the same table.
So it's late and actually can't figure how to do it. Thanks in advance.

I wan't do do something like below in one query, getting 16 rows:

```
SELECT id FROM posts
ORDER BY rates DESC
LIMIT 0,8;


SELECT id FROM posts 
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 0,8;
```

EDIT: Answer:

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM posts ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0,8) AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM posts ORDER BY rates DESC LIMIT 0,8) AS b
```

Comment: whhhhat? post some code or go to bed

Comment: yea i should, here it's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `UNION`

```
(SELECT id FROM posts ORDER BY rates DESC LIMIT 0,8)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id FROM posts ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0,8)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, UNION was the key I was finding. BTW I had to use subqueries like I edited above

Comment: @Fosfor Glad it helped. Parentheses suffice in that case.